# print multiple field from an R dataframe beside eachother

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like my output to be print as each field beside each-other instead of all the values for the first field followed by all the values for the second

This is my script

```
clothing = c('coat_1','coat_1','coat_1','coat_2','coat_2','coat_2','scarf','scarf','scarf')
freq = c(0.3, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1)
temp = c(10, 0, 20, 20, 15, 5, 30, 20, 10)
#exn = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1)

df <- data.frame(clothing, freq, temp)
print(c(toString(df$clothing[df$temp>=20]), toString(df$temp[df$temp>=20])))
```

I get

```
[1] "coat_1, coat_2, scarf, scarf" "20, 20, 30, 20"
```

As output but I would like it output as

```
coot_1 20
coat_2 20
scarf 30
scarf 20
```

Comment: `cat(paste(paste(df$clothing[df$temp>=20], df$temp[df$temp>=20]), collapse = "\n"))`

Comment: Thanks, I'm also trying to write these lines to a file so I'm trying something like `writeLines(cat(paste(paste(df$clothing[df$temp>=20], df$temp[df$temp>=20]), collapse = "\n")), sigMat)` but am receiving `Error in writeLines(cat(paste(paste(df$clothing[df$temp >= 20], df$temp[df$temp >=  : 
  invalid 'text' argument
Execution halted`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Prepare your text
mytext = paste(paste(df$clothing[df$temp>=20], df$temp[df$temp>=20]), collapse = "\n")

#Display in console
cat(mytext)
#coat_1 20
#coat_2 20
#scarf 30
#scarf 20

#Write to a file
cat(mytext, file = "~/test.txt")
```

`cat` can also append to an existing file. You may need to add a line break at the end of the previous text first

```
#Note this time I added a line break ("\n") at the end 
mytext = paste0(paste(paste(df$clothing[df$temp>=20], df$temp[df$temp>=20]),
                                                            collapse = "\n"),"\n")
cat(mytext, file = "~/test.txt") #Check the output file
cat(mytext, file = "~/test.txt", append = TRUE) #Check the output file again
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited to include step to output to file...

```
df.print <- df[which(df$temp>=20),c('clothing', 'temp')]

print(df.print)

write.csv(df.print, file = "c:\\myname\\yourfile.csv")
```